React project image not render in build production (import at 2nd level deep folder)
my folder structure[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/4a5hNCyL.png)
As you see my folder structure in src there are so many folder now in college folder i have also so many folder. now in pages folder i have some page and i import images from assests as you can see from pic 1 there is assests folder. Now all working fine locally but when i build it images are not showing. I do some r n d and found that all images are in ./static/media/ here all my images are present now what i do in chrome developer console i change images location from **./static/media/   to
../static/media/   ** only difference ./static and ../static it will work fine now problem how to get image.enter image description here
i expect in build production of react project all image should show properly

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
